# What replaces FileResolver in the JasperReports API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

One of our software utilities uses a class that implements `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.FileResolver` to load report elements (like images for example) that reside at a path relative to the report or that are to be loaded via a proprietary file server protocol.  As of the latest version, 6.6.0, I see that the plan is to remove the FileResolver class entirely.  However, in the Javadocs, it only notes that the class will be removed.  No details about a replacement are specified.

I am not expecting to be able to trade out the FileResolver with another class with a 1:1 substitution, but would really like to know what the report filler is now using to locate external report elements.

Answer (score 4):

`FileResolver` was deprecated in favor of `net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryService` implementations.

There's a builtin implementation named `net.sf.jasperreports.repo.FileRepositoryService` which is roughly the equivalent of the deprecated `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.SimpleFileResolver`.

Repository services are registered as `JasperReportsContext` extensions.

That can be done either in a jasperreports_extension.properties file like this:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.file.repository=net.sf.jasperreports.repo.FileRepositoryServiceExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.file.repository.root=/path/to/repository
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.persistence=net.sf.jasperreports.repo.FileRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory
```

Registering the extensions can also be done by programmatically creating a `JasperReportsContext` object and then using it to fill the reports:

```
    SimpleJasperReportsContext context = new SimpleJasperReportsContext();
    FileRepositoryService fileRepository = new FileRepositoryService(context, "/path/to/repository", false);
    context.setExtensions(RepositoryService.class, Collections.singletonList(fileRepository));
    context.setExtensions(PersistenceServiceFactory.class, Collections.singletonList(FileRepositoryPersistenceServiceFactory.getInstance()));

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.getInstance(context).fill(jasperReport, params);
```

If you need to implement a custom repository service, you can take `FileRepositoryService` as a reference.  You'll probably want to implement `StreamRepositoryService` and register `PersistenceService`s (as in [FileRepositoryPersistenceServiceFactory](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/repo/FileRepositoryPersistenceServiceFactory.java)).

If what you need to do is about resource paths relative to the report, you can also take a look at the [JRFiller methods](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRFiller.html#fill-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReportsContext-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JasperReportSource-java.util.Map-) that take a `JasperReportSource` argument.  Passing such an object is meant to automatically resolve report resource references as relative to the report (provided that the repository service implements resource lookup based on `RepositoryContext`).

Comment: I had to set a full path in "/path/to/repository". Relative paths or canonical names did not worked.