# Is it possible to include subreport in master report as part of binary file?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I wish to know if there is a way to include a subreport file (or content) in the master report, instead of providing a file path in the master report through a subreport tag:

```
<subreport>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$F{subreportPathFile}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I don't want to have two jasper binaries files but just one.

Comment: `I wish to know if there is a way to include a subreport file (or content) in the master report, instead of provide file path in master report` - AFAIK, it is not possible

Comment: Ok thanks, instead of provide file path String, is it possible to provide bytes array of the subreport ?

Comment: The quote from [javadoc of JRSubreport class](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRSubreport.java): `The so-called subreport expression is introduced by the subreportExpression tag and can return values from the following classes: java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.io.InputStream, java.net.URL, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`

Comment: Yep, I saw that and I'm trying but it's not working.
I read subreport file with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfile.jasper")` and pass it in the Map with `java.io.InputStream` class but I have an error when trying generate pdf : `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream` wrapped `java.io.EOFException: null` and I don't know why...
Any idea please ?

Comment: I don't know your project structure. In case the *myfile.jasper* file is at `resources` folder you can try: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.jasper");`. It is not a *JasperReports* engine problem - you need just to read file right :)

Comment: You can also look at [Reuse subreports across different projects at JasperReports Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51564230/876298) post

Comment: I agree with (my jasper file is in src/main/resources) you but I use same the way to load the subreport as the master report and it is working. That's why I do not understand why it's not working properly :(

Comment: I have not this error anymore but now my generated PDF is empty ^^

Comment: @AlexK I finally succeeded to it that by using java.net.URL and it's working fine.
I get my subreport file with `this.getClass().getResource("subreport_quittance_printing.jasper")` and pass to the map to fill the subreport parameter `<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$F{subreportPathFile}]]></subreportExpression>`
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can mimic subreports with `subDataset` and `datasetRun` for simple use cases. The `jr:listContents` element is similar to a detail band.